# Datepicker doesn't work with bootstrap-modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to implement bootstrap modal on a rails project. It works fine except that my datepicker is not working inside the modal. In my index file I have the following

```
<%= link_to "search_products", search_products_path, remote: true,  "data-toggle" => "modal", 
     'data-target' => '#search-products' %>

<div class="modal fade" id="search-products" tabindex="-1"  
    role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in app/views/products/search_products.js.erb  I have

```
 $("#search-products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'products/search_product') 
  %>")
```

And inside the 'search_product' partial,

```
  <%= text_field_tag :date_purchased, type: "text", placeholder: t('click_here'), 
     class: "form-control date_picker" %>
```

I am using rails4
The datepicker is not from bootstrap and works fine in non-modal pages of my application. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Is my question not clear or not interesting enough to deserve an answer? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this, I use this extensively in my project.

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {

        //Or perhaps any other initializer.
        $('[databehaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker({
            minViewMode: "months",
            format: "MM-yyyy",
            startDate: "today"
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This too didn't work. Even putting the javascript code inside the rendered partial is not working.

Comment: Clear the browser cache and try again .

Comment: I tried it with Firefox and apparently I can see it is hidden behind the modal. What a tragedy! :-)

Answer (score 3):

In your `app/views/products/search_products.js.erb` you must also explicitly initialize the datepicker as you are adding the HTML dynamically into the DOM. So the file should look something like (depending on what datepicker you use):

```
$("#search-products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'products/search_product') %>");
$(".date_picker").datepicker();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, sadly what I get inside the input field even after implementing your suggestion is                                                      {:type=>"text", :placeholder=>"cick_here", :class=>"form-control date_picker"}

Comment: Can you show what the actual rendered HTML looks like inside the modal?

Comment: As I said below on another comment, when I switched from chrome to firefox, I  can see the popup is hidden behind the modal. I am reading about increasing the z-index from other threads. Thanks